# Detecting scroll behavior with css perspective

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, parallax

I have a very simple parallax example set up but am noticing that changes to `window.scrollY` are not occurring (it's always `0`) when scrolling through my elements. It's as if because we're just moving through a perspective, javascript doesn't detect any scrolling.

How can I detect scroll changes when scrolling through css viewport perspective?

I have my css setup as follows:

```
* {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    body {

    }
    .parallax  {
        overflow-x:hidden;
        overflow-y:auto;
        perspective:1px;
        height:200vh;
    }
    .back {
        background-color:#fff;
        height:100vh;
        transform:translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    }
    .base {
        transform:translateZ(0);
        background-color:#fff;
    }
    .parallax__layer {

        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;

        display:block;
    }
    .title {
        text-align:center;
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        top:50%;
        color:blue;
        transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
        display:block;
    }
```

And my dom content is:

```
<div class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax__layer back">
        <div class="title">test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer">
        <div class="title">image</div>

            <div class="frame">
            test frame
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The key here is to detect scroll within the parallax element -- within a single frame div.

So you might do something like:

```
const handleScrolling () => if (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset < totalheight) requestAnimate() 

$('.parallax').on('scroll', handleScrolling);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the overflow property is set on .parallax you would check for scrolling on that instead of the window:

```
$('.parallax').on("scroll", function(){

    var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();

});
```